# iPhone Simulator document directory not found in iOS 8

Tags: xcode6, ios-simulator, osx-yosemite, ios8.1

I am using OS X Yosemite ver 10.10, xcode Version 6.1 (6A1052d), iPhone simulator iOS 8.1 (12B411). I can't find the Developer folder in Library. i

```
NSLog(@"Simualtor Directory %@",[[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject]);

Simualtor Directory file:///Users/gayathiridevi/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/0016A89B-10C4-4BAC-B14B-5731640D3D08/data/Containers/Data/Application/4C7CB382-E3E9-45CB-82F3-9C9F060D62DA/Documents/
```

Sqlite db are in that iPhone simulator directory. How do i find the folder....?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to home folder (Press CMD+SHIFT+H to enter your Home folder in Finder), right click and select Show view options and check the Show Library folder option.
In that Library folder has Developer folder....

Comment: r u looking for document folder or iphone simulator folder or developer folder, which is it?

Answer (score 0):

You can go with the link to check where your simulator folder is located.

Link-[Find Simulator](http://oopstechblog.com/index.php/xcode-6-iphone-simulator-application-and-documents-folders/)

Thanks